# How to achieve Live Search/Filtering on Multiple Fields in the Grid using Ext.Js?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have done live search on grid. it is searching based on which column i mentioned filter code. But i need to filter grid records based on multiple column search. In below code only searches name column because mentioned only the name filed in filter code. I am not getting how to achieve multiple column value search? Can any one tell me how to achieve? great appreciated. Thank you .

**Grid Code Here:**

```
{
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                flex: 2,
                hidden: false,
                store: store,
                loadMask: true,
                id: 'grid',
                columns: [
                    {id:'id',header: 'ID', width: 100, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id'},
                    {header: 'Name', width: 150, dataIndex: 'name'},
                    {header: 'Position', width: 150, dataIndex: 'position'},
                    {header: 'Ambition', width: 250, dataIndex: 'ambition'}                    
                ],
                stripeRows: true,               
                title:'Straw Hats Crew',  
            },
```

**liveSearch text change even Here:**

```
onTextFieldChange: function(field, newValue, oldValue, options){
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
        if(newValue==''){
            grid.store.clearFilter();
        }
        else {
            grid.store.clearFilter();
            grid.store.load().filter([
                {id: 'name', property: "name", value: newValue, anyMatch: true}
            ]);            
        }
    },
```

Comment: The filter method you're using takes an array as an argument. You can add an object for each column you want to filter by. Are you wanting to do an OR instead of an AND? Is that the issue?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I need to do an OR operation. means once if i given some text on textbox, based on textbox value I need to filter related records from all columns. Can you tell me how to achieve? Right now in above code only filtering from name of the column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work. You can specify an arbitrary filter function that can check all the fields in your model.

```
onTextFieldChange: function(field, newValue, oldValue, options){
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
    grid.store.clearFilter();

    if (newValue) {
        var matcher = new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(newValue), "i");
        grid.store.filter({
            filterFn: function(record) {
                return matcher.test(record.get('id')) ||
                    matcher.test(record.get('name')) ||
                    matcher.test(record.get('position')) ||
                    matcher.test(record.get('ambition'));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this call remote store i ned to searching local store